# User defaults for array of objects

Tags: ios, swift, arrayobject, userdefaults

Here is my class that I will make an array of and save it:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Med: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var nombre : String!
    var dias : Int!
    var semanas : Int!
    var minutos : Int!
    var horas : Int!
    var identifiers = [String]()

    init(nombre: String, dias: Int, semanas: Int, minutos: Int, horas: Int, identifiers: [String]) {

        self.nombre = nombre
        self.dias = dias
        self.semanas = semanas
        self.minutos = minutos
        self.horas = horas
        self.identifiers = identifiers

    }

    required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        let nombre = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "nombre") as! String
        let dias = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "dias") as! Int
        let semanas = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "semanas") as! Int
        let minutos = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "minutos") as! Int
        let horas = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "horas") as! Int
        let identifiers = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "identifiers") as! [String]
        self.init(nombre: nombre, dias: dias, semanas: semanas, minutos: minutos, horas: horas, identifiers: identifiers)

   }

   func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

        aCoder.encode(nombre, forKey: "nombre")
        aCoder.encode(dias, forKey: "dias")
        aCoder.encode(semanas, forKey: "semanas")
        aCoder.encode(minutos, forKey: "minutos")
        aCoder.encode(horas, forKey: "horas")
        aCoder.encode(identifiers, forKey: "identifiers")

    }

}
```

Here is the implementation I did using user defaults to save my array of objects:

```
    var userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: listaMeds)
    userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "listaMeds")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
```

And this is how I obtain the data again:

```
let decoded  = userDefaults.object(forKey: "listaMeds") as! Data
listaMeds = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! [Med]
```

However when I close and reopen the app it is not saved. 
Can someone help?

Comment: Not related to the issue but **never ever** declare properties as implicit unwrapped optional which are initialized in an `init` method with non-optional parameters. This is horrible. Declare them as non-optional by removing all exclamation marks. Unfortunately there are countless bad tutorials which suggest that idiocy.

Comment: There is no need to call `synchronize`. Where do you save the data and where do you load it?  Have you used breakpoints to confirm the code is excuting?

Comment: I save the data in an array of objects calles listaMeds and then pass it to user defaults. I have confirmed that the code is executing and it saves it to user defaults and everything, but when I close and reopen the app, the info is not there, it gets erased anyways. @Paulw11